# Accessing different parts of json in a d3 chart function

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to make a function so I can draw three different charts using one set of data.

A sample of the data...

```
var marketshare = [
    {"store": "store1", "share": "5.3%", "q1count": 2, "q2count": 4, "q3count": 0},
    {"store": "store2","share": "1.9%", "q1count": 5, "q2count": 10, "q3count": 0},
    {"store": "store3", "share": "2.5%", "q1count": 3, "q2count": 6, "q3count": 0}
];
```

I'm trying to draw three charts. One with q1count, one with q2count and one with q3count. I created a function that I can call using...

```
drawChart(divID,marketshare,chartWidth,countReference)
```

"divID" is a string identifying where the chart should be drawn.
"marketshare" is the data.
"chartWidth" is the chart width.
"countReference" is a string referring to which data in the object I want to use. For example, this might be "q2count" if I want to access that part of the json.

I'm having a problem stitching together the call to get at that data. Here's an example where I'm trying to log the minimum data point...

```
var minDataPoint = d3.min(marketshare, function(d){
    console.log("min d["+countReference+"] "+d[countReference]); //example return : min d[q2count] undefined
    console.log("min d.q2count "+d.q2count); //example return : min d.q2count 4 
    ...
});
```

I'm thinking I should be able to use the countReference to access the different parts of the json but that's not happening for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would first nest the data by the different qCounts: 
http://matthewfieger.com/posts/me/2014/06/27/nesting_data_for_d3.html

And than create the charts for each nested element.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange to log like that from a `d3` accessor function.  You aren't logging the minimum, you are logging the iterations as `d3` finds the minimum.  Other then that your code works as expected **EXCEPT** (and it's a big except) you need to return *the value of interest* from accessor:

```
var countReference = "q2count";
var marketshare = [
    {"store": "store1", "share": "5.3%", "q1count": 2, "q2count": 4, "q3count": 0},
    {"store": "store2","share": "1.9%", "q1count": 5, "q2count": 10, "q3count": 0},
    {"store": "store3", "share": "2.5%", "q1count": 3, "q2count": 6, "q3count": 0}
];
var minDataPoint  = d3.min(marketshare, function(d,i) {
        console.log("min d["+countReference+"] " + d[countReference]); 
        console.log("min d.q2count " + d["q2count"]);
        return d[countReference]; //<-- return the value of interest which d3 will find the min of
});
console.log(minDataPoint);
```

This outputs:

```
min d[q2count] 4
min d.q2count 4
min d[q2count] 10
min d.q2count 10
min d[q2count] 6
min d.q2count 6
4
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wwzfp9ag/1/).